# Chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate Cannot read property 'callback' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, callback

I want to use the callback of chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate to get the frame information such as frameId and parentFrameId.

code in background page:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(onBeforeNaviCallback);

function onBeforeNaviCallback(detail){

    console.log("frameId" +detail.frameId); 

};//end of onBefore
```

There is alway an error:

```
 Error in event handler for 'webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate': Cannot read property 'callback' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'callback' of undefined
        at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:342:58)
        at dispatchArgs (event_bindings:214:26)
        at Object.chromeHidden.Event.dispatchEvent (event_bindings:223:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order, at the point that line executes it doesn't know what you're talking about.

```
function onBeforeNaviCallback(detail){

    console.log("frameId" +detail.frameId); 

};//end of onBefore

chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(onBeforeNaviCallback);
```

Comment: Function and variable declarations are "executed" before the rest of the code, regardless of their position. This is called [function hoisting](http://jamesallardice.com/explaining-function-and-variable-hoisting-in-javascript/). The OPs code snippet does not contain any errors, (s)he should post the actual code that produces the problem.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  For readability purposes, I'd switch them anyways though, user2694180.